# WPF Treeview with different collections for each depth

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

i am completly new to WPF and need your help. I followed many tutorials but nothing works.

I have two ObserveableLists L1 and L2 to bind and I want to archiev:
On depth 1 - The first List and for each child list 2.

- L1.1

  - L2.1
  - L2.2
  - L2.3
- L1.2

  - L2.1
  - L2.2
  - L2.3
- L1.3

  - L2.1
  - L2.2
  - L2.3

**Update** *16.02.07 - 16:44*

My first try:

```
        <TreeView Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding orderCities}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:city}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding products}" DataType="{x:Type model:Product}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

My second try: Defining two DataTemplates how to handle my types:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{ x:TypeExtension model:city }" ItemsSource="{Binding orderCities}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
            <!-- Here embed Product Type (Dont know how)-->
        </StackPanel>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{ x:TypeExtension model:Product }" ItemsSource="{Binding products}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" - " />
            <TextBox Text="1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And testet both templates and got the right design.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding orderCities}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding orderCities}" />
```

Comment: Start by posting what you've done. Read how to post a [mcve] for help

Answer (score 0):

The treeview alone won't help you here. You have to actually create the data you want to display, i.e. the treeview won't "multiply" the two lists.

Each element in the first list may of course return the same instance of the second list in its children-property. You might want to have look at [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode), it's rather old, but gives a nice introduction on how to use the wpf treeview.